# Rsync --dry-run not showing correct sent bytes

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use `rsyn` with the `--dry-run` option to see if there is enough space for the real synchronization. For test purposes I'm trying to synchronize one directory `Documents`. The size of the directory is

```
  x@x:~$ du Documents
  ...
  640760    Documents/
```

The size of the file container I'm trying to rsync it with is

```
  x@x:~$ df /media/veracrypt2
  Filesystem             1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/veracrypt2      9928  1191      8737  12% /media/veracrypt2
```

Then I run the `rsync` command with:

```
x@x:~$ rsync -ar --dry-run --stats Documents/ /media/veracrypt2

Number of files: 665 (reg: 560, dir: 105)
Number of created files: 664 (reg: 560, dir: 104)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 560
Total file size: 649,731,108 bytes
Total transferred file size: 649,731,108 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 19,429
Total bytes received: 2,115

sent 19,429 bytes  received 2,115 bytes  43,088.00 bytes/sec
total size is 649,731,108  speedup is 30,158.33 (DRY RUN)
```

I don't understand why there were only 19,429 bytes sent? The container is empty so all files of the directory `Documents` should be transferred, menaing 649,731,108!?

I have also tried it with a smaller directory `Scripts` which size is

```
 du -h Scripts/
 32K    Scripts/test/Logs
 56K    Scripts/test
 116K   Scripts/Logs
 264K   Scripts/color_schemes
 580K   Scripts/
```

Here the entire directory should be able to be copied. When running `rsync` for that directory I get the output:

```
sending incremental file list
./
after_install.sh
install-crafter.sh
install-eclipse.sh
mk_autostart_app.sh
package_backup.sh
pandora.sh
sync_script.sh
trackpoint_speed_sens.sh
wallpaper.sh
Logs/
Logs/LOG_SYNC.log
Logs/LOG_SYNC.log~
Logs/LOG_WALLPAPER.txt
Logs/Log_sync.log
Logs/PANDORA.log
Logs/test
color_schemes/
color_schemes/kile.kateschema
test/
test/sync_script.sh
test/Logs/
test/Logs/Log_sync.log

Number of files: 25 (reg: 20, dir: 5)
Number of created files: 22 (reg: 18, dir: 4)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 18
Total file size: 360,658 bytes
Total transferred file size: 353,166 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 900
Total bytes received: 95

sent 900 bytes  received 95 bytes  1,990.00 bytes/sec
total size is 360,658  speedup is 362.47 (DRY RUN)
```

So why is the sent data here only 928 bytes?? Shouldn't that value indicate how many bytes need to be copied to the destination?

Comment: You can add `--verbose` to get the full list of changes that would be done.

Comment: You also didn't show the contents of the source/dest path (or the aforementioned list of changes) to back your claim that "full data is gonna be transferred".

Comment: My guess is that `rsync` only calculates hash differences for file chunks but doesn't transfer actual data. Source code inspection is needed to say for sure (or maybe there's some debug output switch - then the outputs can be diffed).

Comment: Btw your question is actually two in one: 1)the explanation between the numbes; 2)calculating the space needed for sync. I answered both, but the 2nd one probably warrants a separate question for a full answer (code and such).

Answer (score 2):

In `--dry-run` mode, `rsync` determines which files need to be transferred but doesn't actually transfer their data - 'cuz there's no use to do that, naturally. This implies it doesn't perform delta matching - because it's a part of data transfer logic.

The reason for the numbers reflecting that is... well... that the code shows *actual* statistics, not some "would-be" statistics.

Here's a diff between `rsync -avvv --log-file=rsync.log --no-whole-file --stats doc doc2` for the `doc` folder in `rsync` source tree, between `--dry-run` and normal sync (with stripped timestamps, PID differences and heap stats):

```
 delta-transmission enabled
 recv_generator(doc,1)
 recv_generator(doc,2)
+set modtime of doc to (1463404939) Mon May 16 16:22:19 2016
 recv_generator(doc/README-SGML,3)
 recv_generator(doc/profile.txt,4)
 recv_generator(doc/rsync.sgml,5)
 send_files(2, doc)
 cd+++++++++ doc/
 send_files(3, doc/README-SGML)
+send_files mapped doc/README-SGML of size 672
+calling match_sums doc/README-SGML
+sending file_sum
+false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
+>f+++++++++ doc/README-SGML
+sender finished doc/README-SGML
 send_files(4, doc/profile.txt)
+send_files mapped doc/profile.txt of size 1935
+calling match_sums doc/profile.txt
+sending file_sum
+false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
+>f+++++++++ doc/profile.txt
+sender finished doc/profile.txt
 send_files(5, doc/rsync.sgml)
+send_files mapped doc/rsync.sgml of size 11843
+calling match_sums doc/rsync.sgml
+sending file_sum
+false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
+>f+++++++++ doc/rsync.sgml
+sender finished doc/rsync.sgml
 recv_files(1) starting
 recv_files(doc)
 recv_files(doc/README-SGML)
+got file_sum
+set modtime of doc/.README-SGML.hkH0u5 to (1463404939) Mon May 16 16:22:19 2016
+renaming doc/.README-SGML.hkH0u5 to doc/README-SGML
 recv_files(doc/profile.txt)
+got file_sum
+set modtime of doc/.profile.txt.Wdf4x9 to (1463404939) Mon May 16 16:22:19 2016
+renaming doc/.profile.txt.Wdf4x9 to doc/profile.txt
 recv_files(doc/rsync.sgml)
+got file_sum
+set modtime of doc/.rsync.sgml.JSte5H to (1463404939) Mon May 16 16:22:19 2016
+renaming doc/.rsync.sgml.JSte5H to doc/rsync.sgml
 generate_files phase=1
+set modtime of doc to (1463404939) Mon May 16 16:22:19 2016
 send_files phase=1
 recv_files phase=1
 generate_files phase=2
 send_files phase=2
 send files finished
-total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
+total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=14450
 Number of files: 4 (reg: 3, dir: 1)
 Number of created files: 4 (reg: 3, dir: 1)
 Number of deleted files: 0
 Number of regular files transferred: 3
 Total file size: 14,450 bytes
 Total transferred file size: 14,450 bytes
-Literal data: 0 bytes
+Literal data: 14,450 bytes
 Matched data: 0 bytes
 File list size: 0
 File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
 File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
-Total bytes sent: 153
-Total bytes received: 793
-sent 153 bytes  received 793 bytes  378.40 bytes/sec
-total size is 14,450  speedup is 15.27 (DRY RUN)
-[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1196): about to call exit(0) (DRY RUN)
+Total bytes sent: 14,723
+Total bytes received: 1,435
+sent 14,723 bytes  received 1,435 bytes  4,616.57 bytes/sec
+total size is 14,450  speedup is 0.89
+[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1196): about to call exit(0)
```

The following is a diff between the initial dry run and a dry run after I 1)did a real sync, 2) edited one file, `rsync.sgml`. It shows that delta matching is not done in a dry run:

```
 received 3 names
 recv_file_list done
 get_local_name count=4 doc2
-created directory doc2
 delta-transmission enabled
 recv_generator(doc,1)
 recv_generator(doc,2)
 recv_generator(doc/README-SGML,3)
+doc/README-SGML is uptodate
 recv_generator(doc/profile.txt,4)
+doc/profile.txt is uptodate
 recv_generator(doc/rsync.sgml,5)
 send_files(2, doc)
<...>
 Number of files: 4 (reg: 3, dir: 1)
-Number of created files: 4 (reg: 3, dir: 1)
+Number of created files: 0
 Number of deleted files: 0
-Number of regular files transferred: 3
-Total file size: 14,450 bytes
-Total transferred file size: 14,450 bytes
+Number of regular files transferred: 1
+Total file size: 14,476 bytes
+Total transferred file size: 11,869 bytes
 Literal data: 0 bytes
 Matched data: 0 bytes
 File list size: 0
-File list generation time: 0.010 seconds
+File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
 File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
-Total bytes sent: 153
-Total bytes received: 793
-sent 153 bytes  received 793 bytes  1,892.00 bytes/sec
-total size is 14,450  speedup is 15.27 (DRY RUN)
+Total bytes sent: 157
+Total bytes received: 830
+sent 157 bytes  received 830 bytes  658.00 bytes/sec
+total size is 14,476  speedup is 14.67 (DRY RUN)
 [sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1196): about to call exit(0) (DRY RUN)
```

---

Now, regarding your task - to check whether it is enough space on destination for real syncronization.

As you can see from the diff,

- files are copied one by one,
- each file is written to a temporary name, then moved over the original one

So, the amount of space needed at the destination is:

- `sum( max(existing_size,new_size) for all files to be synced) + max( (new_size) for all files to be synced)`

The first term is the worst case scenario for the amount of "final" data at any moment, the second one is the space for a temporary copy.

Each file size can be padded up to a multiple of a storage unit size to allow for wasted space (if applicable for the target FS and the total expected amount is high enough to make a difference).

Comment: That sees quite complicated though, isn't there any other command to check if there is enough space for a synchronization?

Comment: @wasp256 well, you can get a crude conservative approximation: total size of the local folder times the maximum expected ratio of `new_size/old_size` (no more than 1.1-1.2 probably) plus the size of the largest file. It's more than enough in virtually all cases: if you're running out of disk space so badly that you need more precision, it's probably a sign that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Okay thx for the answer

Comment: One last question, I just saw the line `Total transferred file size: 353,166 bytes` in the stats output, aren't those the bytes that would need to be transmitted in the real transmission?

Comment: @wasp256 No, it's the _"total sum of all files sizes for just the transferred files":_ http://www.lbackup.org/backup_statistics . The net unmatched data size is "Literal data" which is 0 for a dry run. Anyway, why are you interested in transmission volume? You were interested in the disk space required at destination (which is a different thing, as you can see from the answer).